# Making Xcode custom output "clickable" to the code line

Tags: xcode, xcode7, intel-composer

I have a custom build step that may produce errors. The build is actually an Intel Compiler for C++, and the errors have the form:

> MyCode.cpp(18): error #77: this declaration has no storage class or
>   type specifier

Since this is not a native Xcode build, clicking this error line will not bring you to the code, and you have to manually navigate to the code.

How can I tell Xcode to treat this error as an Xcode native error?

Comment: I think it has to have the form `filename.ext:linenumber: whatever`. So, for your case: `MyCode.cpp:18: error #77...`

Comment: Not that. Even with your suggested form it doesn't work.